# Query is taking hours to complete, Query is really slow because of multiple joins and unions on huge data set, maybe index is wrong?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, execution-time

I have this long query which I want to save as a stored procedure and use it later in etl jobs. It affects approximately 15+ million rows and is taking more than 1 and a half hour to complete. I am using postgres and pgadmin.

Code:

```
INSERT INTO t_temporary_id_table ( 
    ref_date,
    id,
    client, 
    slcunda,
    count_single_1,         
    count_double_2,         
    count_e, 
    count_g, 
    count_m, 
    active, 
    valid_till_max, 
    id_2, 
    created ,
    lastmodified 
    )
with 
cte_tmp as (
    select 
        a.id,               
        mm.tenant,          
        c.slcunda,              
        d.single,           
        d.count_single,   
        e.double_1,         
        e.count_double_1,     
        SUM (CASE WHEN id_role = 'E' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "count_e",  
        SUM (CASE WHEN id_role = 'G' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "count_g",  
        SUM (CASE WHEN id_role = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "count_m",  
        case when min(status)='active' then 1 else 0 end active, 
        MAX(valid_till) as valid_till_max
        
    from schema1.struct a
    inner join 
    (
    select 
        id,
        max(valid_till) valid_till_max
    from 
        schema1.struct a
    group by 
        id
    ) b
    on 
    a.id=b.id and a.valid_till = b.valid_till_max
    left outer join 
    schema2.tenants mm on a.tsl_1_2 = mm.tenant 
    left outer join (
        select 
            id,
            key_1 as slcunda
        from    
            schema1.t_id 
        where 
            id in (Select id from schema1.t_id group by id having count(id)=1) 
    ) c
    on a.id=c.id
    left outer join(
        select 
        id,
        count_single,
        single 
        from (
            select
                id, 
                id_2 as single,
                id_2_role,
                count(id) over(partition by id) as count_single,
                row_number() over(partition by id order by id, id_2_role desc) as rn
            from 
                schema1.different_id_2
            where 
                id_2_role in ('03','08','17')   
            ) a
        where rn=1
    ) d
    on a.id=d.id
    left outer join(
        select 
        id,
        count_double_1,
        double_1
        from (
            select
                id, 
                id_2 as double_1,
                id_2_role,
                count(id) over(partition by id) as count_double_1,
                row_number() over(partition by id order by id, id_2_role desc) as rn 
            from 
                schema1.different_id_2
            where 
                id_2_role in ('06','19')    
        ) a
    where rn=1
    ) e 
    on a.id=e.id    
    group by a.id,mm.client,c.slcunda,d.single,d.count_single,e.double_1,e.count_double_1
),
y as ( 
    select * 
    from (
        SELECT 
            cte_tmp.id,
            client,
            slcunda,
            count_single as count_single_1, 
            count_double_1 as count_double_2, 
            count_e,
            count_g,
            count_m,
            active,
            valid_till_max,
            b.id_2 
        FROM 
            cte_tmp
        inner join (
            select 
                id,
                id_2
            from (
                select 
                    id,
                    id_theory as id_2,
                    row_number() over(partition by id) rn
                from
                    schema1.struct
            ) a 
        where rn=1  
        ) b
        on cte_tmp.id=b.id
        where
            count_e=1 and count_g=0 and count_m=0 and count_single=0 
        union all   
        SELECT 
            id,
            client,
            slcunda,
            count_single as count_single_1, 
            count_double_1 as count_double_2, 
            count_e,
            count_g,
            count_m,
            active,
            valid_till_max,
            single as id_2 
        FROM 
            cte_tmp
        where 
            count_e=1 and count_g=0 and count_m=0 and count_single>=1
        union all
        SELECT
            id,
            client,
            slcunda,
            count_single as count_single_1, 
            count_double_1 as count_double_2, 
            count_e,
            count_g,
            count_m,
            active,
            valid_till_max,
            double_1 as id_2 
        FROM 
            cte_tmp
        where
            count_e=0 and count_g=1 and count_m>=1 and active=1 and count_double>=1
        union all
        SELECT 
            id,
            client,
            slcunda,
            count_single as count_single_1, 
            count_double_1 as count_double_2, 
            count_e,
            count_g,
            count_m,
            active,
            valid_till_max,
            double_1 as id_2 
        FROM 
            cte_tmp
        where 
            count_e<>1 and count_g<>0 and count_m<>=0 and active=0 and count_double>=1
    ) a 
), 


z as (
    SELECT 
        cte_tmp.id,
        client,
        slcunda,
        count_single as count_single_1, 
        count_double_1 as count_double_2,
        count_e,
        count_g,
        count_m,
        active,
        valid_till_max
    FROM cte_tmp
    except
    select 
        id,
        client,
        slcunda,
        count_single_1,
        count_double_2,
        count_e,
        count_g,
        count_m,
        active,
        valid_till_max
    from y
),

temporary_result as (
    select 
        id::bigint,
        client,
        slcunda,
        count_single_1,
        count_double_2,
        count_e,
        count_g,
        count_m,
        active,
        valid_till_max,
        '' as id_2
    from z
    union all
    select 
        id::bigint,
        client,
        slcunda,
        count_single_1,
        count_double_2,
        count_e,
        count_g,
        count_m,
        active,
        valid_till_max,
        id_2
    from y
)
select 
    now(),
    id,
    client,
    slcunda,
    count_single_1, 
    count_double_2, 
    count_e,
    count_g,
    count_m,
    active,
    valid_till_max,
    id_2::bigint,
    now(),
    now()
from temporary_result
```

I have indexes on

1. schema1.struct table columns 'id' and 'valid_till'
2. schema1.t_id table column 'id'
3. schema1.different_id_2 table columns 'id' and 'id_2_role'

I am new to this so any recommendations would be appreciated.

Explain query result is following:

```
#   Node    Rows    Loops
```

Actual

1. Aggregate (rows=13953682 loops=1)   13953682    1
2. Sort (rows=15791738 loops=1)    15791738    1
3. Hash Left Join (rows=15791738 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (a.id = a_2.id)
   15791738    1
4. Hash Left Join (rows=15791738 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (a.id = a_1.id)
   15791738    1
5. Hash Right Join (rows=15791738 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (t_id.id = a.id)
   15791738    1
6. Hash Inner Join (rows=60629 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (t_id.id = t_id_1.id)
   60629   1
7. Seq Scan on t_id as t_id (rows=45144181 loops=1)    45144181    1
8. Hash (rows=60629 loops=1)
   Buckets: 131072 Batches: 2 Memory Usage: 2241 kB
   60629   1
9. Aggregate (rows=60629 loops=1)
   Filter: (count(t_id_1.id) = 1)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 15056381
   60629   1
10. Gather Merge (rows=31764065 loops=1)    31764065    1
11. Aggregate (rows=10588022 loops=3)   10588022    3
12. Sort (rows=15048060 loops=3)    15048060    3
13. Seq Scan on t_id as t_id_1 (rows=15048060 loops=3)  15048060    3
14. Hash (rows=15791738 loops=1)
    Buckets: 65536 Batches: 512 Memory Usage: 3585 kB
    15791738    1
15. Gather (rows=15791738 loops=1)  15791738    1
16. Hash Left Join (rows=5263913 loops=3)
    Hash Cond: (a.tsl_1_2 = (mm.tenant)::numeric)
    5263913 3
17. Hash Inner Join (rows=5263913 loops=3)
    Hash Cond: ((a.id = struct.id) AND (a.valid_till = (max(struct.valid_till))))
    5263913 3
18. Seq Scan on struct as a (rows=5292460 loops=3)  5292460 3
19. Hash (rows=13953682 loops=3)
    Buckets: 131072 Batches: 256 Memory Usage: 3575 kB
    13953682    3
20. Aggregate (rows=13953682 loops=3)   13953682    3
21. Sort (rows=15877381 loops=3)    15877381    3
22. Seq Scan on struct as struct (rows=15877381 loops=3)    15877381    3
23. Hash (rows=54 loops=3)
    Buckets: 1024 Batches: 1 Memory Usage: 11 kB
    54  3
24. Seq Scan on tenants as mm (rows=54 loops=3) 54  3
25. Hash (rows=7983 loops=1)
    Buckets: 8192 Batches: 1 Memory Usage: 634 kB
    7983    1
26. Subquery Scan (rows=7983 loops=1)
    Filter: (a_1.rn = 1)
    Rows Removed by Filter: 12669
    7983    1
27. Sort (rows=20652 loops=1)   20652   1
28. Window Aggregate (rows=20652 loops=1)   20652   1
29. Window Aggregate (rows=20652 loops=1)   20652   1
30. Sort (rows=20652 loops=1)   20652   1
31. Gather (rows=20652 loops=1) 20652   1
32. Seq Scan on different_id_2 as different_id_2 (rows=6884 loops=3)
    Filter: (id_2_role = ANY ('{3,8,17}'::numeric[]))
    Rows Removed by Filter: 1798703
    6884    3
33. Hash (rows=1815522 loops=1)
    Buckets: 65536 Batches: 64 Memory Usage: 3585 kB
    1815522 1
34. Subquery Scan (rows=1815522 loops=1)
    Filter: (a_2.rn = 1)
    Rows Removed by Filter: 3589410
    1815522 1
35. Sort (rows=5404932 loops=1) 5404932 1
36. Window Aggregate (rows=5404932 loops=1) 5404932 1
37. Window Aggregate (rows=5404932 loops=1) 5404932 1
38. Sort (rows=5404932 loops=1) 5404932 1
39. Seq Scan on different_id_2 as different_id_2_1 (rows=5404932 loops=1)
    Filter: (id_2_role = ANY ('{6,19}'::numeric[]))
    Rows Removed by Filter: 11829
    5404932 1

But I dont understand this much!

Comment: you can run your query with `explain analyze` in order to see the query plan and what takes so much time

Comment: What is the purpose of the row_number() window functions without an order by clause?

Comment: Added the explain analyze @SvetlinZarev

Comment: I wasnt sure about order by ,but now added it in the code @Jeremy

Comment: Which Postgres version? (if below 11: get reid of the CTEs!)